# How to Fix #Error When Calculating a DateDiff With an IIF Statement in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, datediff, iif

I'm creating a report in Reporting Services to display time-spans for classroom sessions in our program. One column that was requested is to show the total number of hours between the start and end time of one session. I used a DATEDIFF function showing the DateInterval in hours as the total hours in one time-span, but I get a #Error returned for the blank values that haven't been assigned a begin or end time.

I added an IIF statement to mark the values that are blank as "TBA", but that didn't work. Since I'm casting a string to a datetime value, I enclosed the DATEDIFF statement in a CStr function, but that also isn't working. Lastly, I did the simple thing and set the text box to display a Number value since it's returning the total number of hours, but of course, that didn't work either. My code is as follows:

```
=IIF(Fields!BeginTime.Value = "", "TBA", CStr(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!BeginTime.Value, Fields!EndTime.Value)))
```

It's supposed to show that "TBA" value in the blank spots, but I still get a #Error. The total hours are coming up fine for the values that aren't blank, however. I checked the value in the dataset to see if it's returning a blank or a NULL-labeled value, and it is returning a blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is arising in the conditional statement.  If `Fields!BeginTime.Value` is a date datatype, comparing it to `""` will likely result in the error you're getting.  I suggest using the `IsNothing` function or just checking if the field is nothing.  The two options are as follows.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!BeginTime.Value), ...
```

Or...

```
=IIF(Fields!BeginTime.Value Is Nothing, ...
```

With that said, you shouldn't need to use the `CStr` as `DateDiff` will return an integer value.  Your textbox should be set to `Default` or some text variant to prevent errors there.  The expression will return either an integer or string so a number format on the textbox will not work.

Additionally, if you're having the same issue when there is no `EndTime`, you may want to add an `OR` to the conditional to fix that.

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!BeginTime.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!EndTime.Value), ...
```

Comment: Those are all really good ideas, but I seem to still be getting that error. I tried both methods, added the `OR` for the `EndTime`, removed the `CStr` and set the text box to Default.

Comment: @KendallI. I have a feeling this might be a datatype issue...  Are you sure both values are dates?  Might be worth trying to add a `CDate()` to each field in the `DateDiff` just to be sure.

Comment: Good catch! I just checked and the datatype for both of these fields is varchar.
So, I changed my code and added a `CDate()` to each field in the `DateDiff`.
Verify that my code is correct for this? 
`IIF(IsNothing(Fields!BeginTime.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!EndTime.Value), "TBA", DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, CDate(Format(CDate(Fields!BeginTime.Value),"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")), CDate(Format(CDate(Fields!EndTime.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))))`

Comment: @KendallI. That should work, but I'm not sure why you're converting, then formatting back to string, then converting again.  Is the `VARCHAR` field from the DB formatting `MM/dd/yyyy`?  You should just be able to use a single `CDate`.  One minor typo, the `FORMAT` on BeginTime should be `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: The varchar field is "HH:MM" then AM or PM. I thought I had added an extra step in the conversion, I just wasn't sure. Thanks for finding the typo as well!

Comment: Would it maybe work to convert the fields in the SQL query and then work with that instead?

Comment: @KendallI. That would probably be ideal.  Probably something like `getdate()+substring([YourColHere], 1, Length([YourColHere]) - 2(or 3?))` would get you close.  Might need to do some magic with AM vs. PM (such as adding 12 to any with PM)

Comment: I fixed it by using a CASE statement with a DATEDIFF embedded within to mark the blank values as NULL, then used an IIF statement in SSRS to mark the NULL values as "TBA".